# Как правильно настроить $stateProvider в ui-router (angular) для работы с двумя ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router, ui-router

на форме есть два именованных ui-view

```
<div ui-view="form"></div>
<div ui-view="body"></div>
```

В одном, по задумке, должны отображаться формы (авторизация и т.д.), во втором сама страница. Задумка такая, что бы при авторизации или любом появлении формы  на странице продолжал отображаться контент в `<div ui-view="body"></div>`. Но не получается. $stateProvider организован как-то так:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    views: {
      body: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/page.about.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    views: {
      form: {templateUrl: 'templates/form.auth.html'}
    }
  })
```

Сейчас, если путь /auth то в `<div ui-view="body"></div>` пусто. Подскажите, как правильно настроить $stateProvider, что бы контент из body не пропадал.

Comment: судя по аналогичному [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1grdcvc3ZGaMRTu0xGtG?p=preview) все работает, можете его поменять так, чтобы ваша проблема воспроизвелась?

Comment: Вот именно, что в Вашем планкере воспроизводится моя ситуация один в один. Нужно что бы оба ui-view одновременно отображали информацию.

Comment: тогда поведение абсолютно логичное - вы указываете один view - он и заполняется. Если укажете два -заполнятся два. мне кажется вопрос нужно конкретизировать, возможно привести картинки как сейчас и как хотите чтобы было

Comment: к тому же если вы хотите показывать одни и те же view - зачем вам два  state?

Comment: Мне кажется что я выразился однозначно. Вью form предназначено только для форм. А вью body - для контента. Т.к. форма может появиться при любом контенте и он при этом не должен пропасть и было создано два вью. Т.к. контент в body в момент появления формы может быть любым - я для state: auth не описывал view: body. Возможно есть способ прописать вью body динамически, подставив туда текущее содержимое body в момент показа формы?

Comment: не, было неоднозначно, да и теги не показывались.

Comment: вот эту часть, что-то совсем не понял: _Т.к. контент в body в момент появления формы может быть любым - я для state: auth не описывал view: body. Возможно есть способ прописать вью body динамически, подставив туда текущее содержимое body в момент показа формы_? у вас body может из разных шаблонов подгружаться или как?

Comment: можете отредактировать планкер добавив в него несколько возможных сценариев? Потому что решение для конкретного предоставленного в вопросе кода - добавить боди в auth, но судя по комментарию вам это не подходит, кроме того не совсем понятно какое ожидается значение боди, если вы стоите в стейте auth - он на данный момент сам по себе и никак с боди не связан

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю Вас! Я понял свою ошибку. Вынесу auth из состояний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вы имеете два не связанных между собой состояния, в каждом из которых устанавливается только одно из двух view.

самое простое решение добавить в состояние оба view

```
.state('about', {
  url: '/about',
  views: {
    body: {
      templateUrl: 'templates/page.about.html'
    },
    form: {
      templateUtl: '...'
    }
  }
})
```

Кроме того, значением `templateUtl` может быть функция, в которой можно проверить какие-нибудь условия и вернуть url, в этом случае форма покажется, либо не вернуть ничего, в этом случае форма не покажется.

```
form:{
  templateUrl: function(){
    if(something)
        return 'state2.html'
  }
}
```

В качестве одного из решений можно так же использовать [nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views) - вложенные состояния и вложенные view.

Идея заключается в том, что добавляется вложенное состояние *auth* устанавливающее view только для формы

```
.state('about.auth', {
  url: "/auth",
  views: {
    'form@': {
      templateUrl: 'state2.html'
    }
  }
})
```

[**Рабочий пример на Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMV7OGjvzsBTcYuCboPL?p=preview)